# Front-end application throwing an error due to it being unable to load the webpack.config.js

Tags: java, vaadin

I've been attempting to solve this bug for the better part of 5 hours now. Essentially when updating my Vaadin application from Vaadin 14 to Vaadin 23 many bugs have taken over my program. I have solved the majority of them but this one is really confusing me. This is the error it shows:

```
[38;5;196m
------------------ Frontend compilation failed. ------------------

[0m2022-04-13 21:04:08.286  INFO 18612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-13 21:04:08.286  INFO 18612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-13 21:04:08.287  INFO 18612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-04-13 21:04:08.335  INFO 18612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator  : The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
2022-04-13 21:04:08.341 ERROR 18612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.v.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler      : 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Startup of Webpack failed. Output was:
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'object.getownpropertydescriptors'
Require stack:
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\util.promisify\implementation.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\util.promisify\index.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\webpack.generated.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\webpack.config.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Java Projects\GitHub\Availaboard\availaboard-project\node_modules\util.promisify\implementation.js:12:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\node_modules\\util.promisify\\implementation.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\node_modules\\util.promisify\\index.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\node_modules\\html-webpack-plugin\\index.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\webpack.generated.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Java Projects\\GitHub\\Availaboard\\availaboard-project\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}

    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.doStartDevModeServer(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:217) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.runOnFutureComplete(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:169) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.lambda$new$0(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:160) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.4.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:483) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) ~[na:na]

2022-04-13 21:04:08.342 ERROR 18612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[springServlet]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [springServlet] threw exception
```

The error repeats itself a couple of times.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.availaboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>availaboard</artifactId>
    <name>Availaboard</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.0.4</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur.exampledata</groupId>
            <artifactId>exampledata</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                             the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                      Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                      package.json and main.js files.
                      It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
                  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Use the latest released version:
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                <version>1.8.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids, but it looks nice in your build log. -->
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v16.14.0</nodeVersion>

                    <!-- optional: with node version greater than 4.0.0 will use npm provided by node distribution -->
                    <!--                    <npmVersion>2.15.9</npmVersion>-->

                    <!-- optional: where to download node and npm from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
                    <!--                    <downloadRoot>http://myproxy.example.org/nodejs/</downloadRoot>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                            <pnpmEnable>false</pnpmEnable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Totally wild guess.. you tried in another folder where the parent folders have no space in the name?

Comment: @Knoobie What do you mean?

Comment: In your path is a space "C:\Java Projects\..." - try it with a folder structure without space (" ") like java_projects to see if that makes a difference